# How to remove Title Bar from Activity extending ActionBarActivity or AppcompatActivity with Dialog Theme

Tags: android, title, appcompatactivity, android-appcompat

I had to extend my Activity with theme Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog from ActionBarActivity before and now from AppcompatActivity, because my Base Activity extends this one.

But now with new appcompat v7 (v22) library my Activity started to show title bar despite the fact that i use custom style with items windowActionBar=false, android:windowNoTitle=true. But until appcompat library upgraded there isn't such problem, title bar wasn't showed.

If my activity extends FragmentActivity everything is ok and i understand that maybe i use a bad pattern that my dialog activity extends from AppcompatActivity but i would like to know is there a way to remove title bar?

Comment: why dont you just extend activity

Comment: because the activty inherits some common things from a base class activty that extends AppCompatActivity. In my app almost all activities extend this base.

Comment: @MikhailKharbanov Did you find the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 73):

I had same issue and needed to do something like following to resolve (note use of "windowNoTitle" instead of "android:windowNoTitle")

```
<style name="Theme.MyDialog" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: @Mikhail This should be the accepted answer. Works! :)

Comment: Thanks, answer is true..:)

Comment: i tried so many ridiculous things before this simple answer worked!

Comment: The note (use of "windowNoTitle" instead of "android:windowNoTitle") is crucial!

Answer (score 20):

Try

```
  getSupportActionBar().hide()
```

if you are using AppCompatActivity

And

```
 getActionBar().hide()
```

if your activity extends ActionBarActivity. 
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 16):

You can hide the action bar at runtime by calling `hide()`. For example:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

Comment: Android Studio complained until I wrapped the actionBar.hide(); in a null check: if (actionBar != null) {actionBar.hide();}

Answer (score 12):

Only one thing work in AppCompat Theme -
`supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

Answer (score 9):

To solve the actionbar on class extend AppCompatActivity I start with define new theme extend from main theme in style.xml file :

**style.xml**

```html
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

and implement noactionbar theme to activity that you want in AndroidManifest.xml. Hope this help :)

Answer (score 8):

If you're using support library use:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

If not then use

```
getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Comment: None of the style based method worked for me (my Activity inherits from AppCompatActivity); but this one did: thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Adding `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"` in `AndroidManifest.xml` does the trick in my case.

@Brexx Galangue solution gave me the following runtime error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use 
>       a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: I also get this error, but `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"` is unkown in my case.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add this code on your manifest, specifically, to the activity that you want to disappear its `Actionbar`:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
```

hope it helps :D

Answer (score -1):

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
     getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_title_bar);

  }  
}
```

Comment: where is `R.layout.custom_title_bar` coming from?

Comment: res/layout/custom_title_bar.xml